# obtain the decimal value from a hexadecimal string

Tags: python

I'm having some troubles converting a hexadecimal value to decimal. Theoretically is easy with `Python`:

```
value = '000100000001f8c65400fefe3195000001230000000000000000000000000000000000000000642b00090700000000001e'
print(int(value,16))
```

And this is the result:

`153914086775326342143664486282692693880080977757509806775956245674142536051238079779640236240803190331364310253598`

Since here all is ok.

This string represents a payload of different bytes and I know two things:

- 1 byte = 8 bits.
- Hexadecimal values are usually represented with two hexadecimal values, like `FF 2E 32 etc`.

The problem comes when I want to work with some concrete byte, because theoretically I know that in the byte 18, 19, 20 and 21 I have some decimal number that starts in 39 (I don't know the other numbers that follow). But when I want to decode it I can't find it.

```
# First try
a = value[36:43] # 18*2 to 21*2
print(a)
print(int(a,16))

# Second try
a = value[18:22] # 18 to 21
print(a)
print(int(a,16))
```

With a naked eye, I can see that the third and fourth value in the first result is this `39`,

`153914086775326342143664486282692693880080977757509806775956245674142536051238079779640236240803190331364310253598`

But another time, if I do

```
# third try
a = value[2:4]
print(a)
print(int(a,16))
```

I can't find this 39, and the values change from the first result.

How I have to do it? I'm sure is easy but I don't know how to do it. I want to learn to access to the different bytes but I can't understand the logic.

**EDIT trying to explain it better**

I have this hexadecimal payload:

`153914086775326342143664486282692693880080977757509806775956245674142536051238079779640236240803190331364310253598`

And this represents the set of different values collected in bytes.

Therefore, what I try is to be able to access a byte (or a set) to know what its value would be in decimal. For example, I know that byte 18 to 21 is the latitude and byte 39 the battery. How can I decode it with `python`?

(In my city the latitude always starts in 39, that's what I said before this)

Thank you very much

Comment: Converting that whole hex string to an integer was meaningless, as the hex data doesn't represent a single number, it's probably many numbers (of possibly different bit sizes) packed together.  `binascii.unhexlify()`, possibly followed by `struct.unpack()`, would be a more likely approach to working with it.

Comment: The `39` only exists in the decimal representation (i.e. under base-10) - asking for which specific hexadecimal representation (under base-16) in the original value borders on nonsense, given that base 10 and base 16 are not integer multiples of each other. Try comparing `0x05a947` vs `0x02586e` and see where the literals `10` `15` and `37` in the base-10 representations are in the provided base-16 representations.  What you probably want to do is convert each 2-character pair into a corresponding base-10 representation in the range of 0-255. You may wish to update the question to reflect this

Comment: Yesss, sorry my English is not very good, especially when I don't understand about the question. I try to update the question but is what @jasonharper says, this whole number are many numbers packed and I have to unpack in decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be very confused about number bases.  Please look up proper terminology, as well.  For instance:

> Hexadecimal values are usually represented with two hexadecimal values, like FF 2E 32 etc

I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.  You seem to have noticed that hex values are often separated into bytes (each hex-digit is 4 bits),  but the way you express it makes me wonder what you mean.  The byte-level separation is not a "representation"; rather, it's a reading convenience.

Your central question seems to be how to find a particular decimal subsequence coded into only a subsequence of the hexidecimal version.  Have you confused character coding (such as ASCII, UniCode, or EBCDIC) with simple base representation?  Character coding allows you to make this sub-string conversion; changing number bases is not at all the same operation.  For instance:

```
base 16  base 10
    1        1
   21       33 = 2 * 16 + 1
  B21     2849 = 11 * 16*16 + 2 * 16 + 1
  B2       178 = 11 * 16 + 2
  B         11
```

There is *no* subsequence in one base that is coded with a subsequence in the other base.  For instance, the "84" in base 10 is a notational feature of the *entire* hexadecimal number, *not* any subsequence.